# No GUI after Ubuntu 16.04 is installed

Tags: 16.04, graphics, gui

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 instead of opening my computer to a nice purple GUI, I'm instead taken to a black background boot screen, where some text runs across the screen for 5 seconds before I'm taken to a screen that just says:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS steve tty1
steve login: steve
Password:
Last login: Fri Aug 5 11:28:38 CEST 2016 on tty1
E: Error: BrokenCount > Orun-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available exited with return code 255
To run a command as administrator (user "root'), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
steve@steve:~$
```